# jwt secret key storage in java web application

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, tomcat7, jwt, secret-key

I implemented some count of JAX-RS web services using jersey. Now I want to protect them. I chose JWT for that. I have only one question: where should I store a secret key in my Java Web App (deployed on Tomcat)?? What is the best solution? Unfortunately I couldn't find any clear solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look to [where to store a key for enctyption](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12332/where-to-store-a-key-for-encryption)